# Any SE sites with independent hosting?

Tags: discussion

Are there any [SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) which have independent hosting (i.e. they run SE software but not on SE servers)? Or all SE sites are hosted on SE servers?

Comment: Everything public runs on SE servers, including SO for teams. SE enterprise comes with a private hosting offering.

Comment: for a good read: https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/03/29/stack-overflow-the-hardware-2016-edition/

Comment: Why do you ask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, *all public* SE sites runs on SE's own servers. Additionally, Stack Overflow for Teams (SO Teams) runs on SE's servers as well, but with a different content policy*. The only SE software that doesn't run on SE's servers is SO Enterprise.

Talking about content, all public text content are hosted by SE themselves, but many assets are hosted outside. For example, user images are often hosted on Imgur, and user avatars on Imgur, WordPress (Gravatar) and Google.

* <sup>SO Teams content is not monitored or viewed by SE employees. It's only accessed upon support request.</sup>

Comment: Re: *"The only SE software that doesn't run on SE's servers is SO Enterprise."*: Long before SO Enterprise, in the early days of Stack Overflow, the source code was [sold to 5 companies (the four mentioned are Microsoft, Bloomberg, Capital One, and Credit Suisse) for USD 100,000 per year](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMfxd9y0cMY&t=23m7s) (with no support whatsoever, but no strings attached, except for in-house use only). (Capital One: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_One?. [Credit Suisse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_Suisse).)

Comment: cont': Today [Microsoft and other big companies pay at least USD 1,000,000 per year](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMfxd9y0cMY&t=27m40s). (Information for avoiding the ads in the referenced YouTube video: [00 min 00 secs; 00 min 52 secs], [09 min 18 secs; 11 min 33 secs], [28 min 40 secs; 30 min 58 secs], and [43 min 54 secs; 45 min 47 secs].)